# How can I make the Y axis in a Unovis chart start at 0?

Tags: visualization

The Y axis seems to be dynamic and depends on the data.

Code:

```
import { VisAxis, VisLine, VisXYContainer } from '@unovis/react'
import { data } from './data'

export default function() {
return (
  <VisXYContainer data={data}>
    <VisLine x={d => d.x} y={d => d.y}/>
    <VisAxis type='x'/>
    <VisAxis type='y'/>
  </VisXYContainer>
)
```

Looks like: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P8ov.png)

Is there a way to make it start at 0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the Y axis range (or the Y scale domain in D3 terms) for all XY components (Line, Area, Scatter, etc ...) by setting the yDomain property of XYContainer.

Here's an example in React:

```
<VisXYContainer yDomain={[0, undefined]} ...>
  <VisLine ... >
</VisXYContainer>
```

The yDomain value of [0, undefined] means that the lower limit will be 0 and the upper limit will be determined automatically based on the data.

You can read more about controlling the chart's scales in the documentation: https://unovis.dev/docs/xy-charts/Container#ydomain